# I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it comes without apps

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome-terminal, browser, filemanager

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi. I had some trouble accessing the desktop and had to install a screen manager, and when I finally managed to turn it on, there weren’t any apps! No browser, the terminal and file manager don’t work… All I have is the Settings app, and an empty desktop.

Comment: What Ubuntu 20.04 system did you install?  Was it a Server? (no desktop/GUI) or a Desktop. You mention a *screen manager* so what specifically did you install?  Did you install a desktop? a window manager? or what? as installing a installing a simple WM results in a basic GUI or graphical user interface, but no GUI apps; even a basic desktop (including WM) may not include any apps. Do you have a desktop? if so what did you install? (*A desktop consists of many parts including WM & other components, some meta packages include apps where as others do not; a WM alone has no apps*)